# C# How to inherit class from abstract generic class with generic class as type parameter

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

I have the following abstract classes:

```
public abstract class Entry;
public abstract class Table<TEntry> where TEntry : Entry;
public abstract class Parser<TTable> where TTable : Table<Entry>;
```

`Entry` is a base class for a table entry containing a Dictionary of data.

`Table` is a base class for a table containing IEnumerables of Entries plus some other info.

`Parser` is a base class for text parsers which can read in strings and turn them into Entries for their ICollection of Entries, and can convert their ICollection to a Table.

```
public class MyEntry : Entry;
public class MyTable : Table<MyEntry>;
public class MyParser : Parser<MyTable>;
```

Upon trying to implement children of these base classes like so, I get the error CS0311: `The type 'MyTable' cannot be used as type parameter 'TTable' in the generic type or method 'Parser<TTable>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyTable' to 'Table<Entry>'`.

However, `out` can only be specified on generic types of interfaces. I need to use an abstract class here since there is some base class behavior that I want to be protected, not public.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include minimal code that fails with thar error message?

Comment: A `Table<MyEntry>` isn't a `Table<Entry>`, they are different types.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need generics.  It sounds very specific.

Comment: `out` only makes sense for a "returning" position, which isn't usually useful in an `abstract` class. This is why they haven't bothered to implement it. What functionality do you need in the base class that you cannot use interfaces?

Comment: @Charlieface I need the Parser to use the MyTable type because that has properties that Table doesn't, which the Parser needs to assign when creating a new MyTable. I ended up using an interface IParser and gave MyParser<ITable> read-only properties of type ITable that just return the value from a private MyTable field. Bit of an ugly work around but it seems to do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is not eligible for class [as msdn says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

- Variant type parameters are restricted to **generic interface and generic delegate types**

So variant type parameters for class are not covariant. "Covariant" means that assignment of derived class copmatible with base type:

```
public class Fruit
{ 
}

public class Apple : Fruit
{ }
```

And this code is perfectly eligible:

```
IEnumerable<Fruit> fruits = new List<Apple>();
```